# How to read value using JQuery and calling a Webservice

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

I have a situation where I need to get the total number of records in order to calculate the number of pages.

As for now i'm storing the "Total Record" in asp:label control.

So, I would like how to read/get the value of "Total Record" without asp:label control.

**Here's my code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //
    GetTotalRecord();

});


function GetTotalRecord() 
{

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ws/service.asmx/TotalRecord",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: CalculateTotalRecord,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });

}


function CalculateTotalRecord(xml) 
{
    $('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(xml.d);


    //alert($('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').text() );

    v_page_max = Math.ceil ($('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').text() / v_page_size) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your URL is correct for the service
2. Verify if your service is returning JSON
3. understand you JSON object and read the right property

   ```
   function GetTotalRecord() 
       {
           $.ajax(
           {
               type: "GET", // should be a get 
               url: "../ws/service.asmx/TotalRecord", // Confirm if this URL is right?
               //data: "{}", // not required if you dont have parameters
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data){
                   // if in case your service is returning JSON as string 
                   // then you will have to parse the string to JSON
                   // var result = JSON.Parse(data);
                   //Now read from result
                   //alert(data.d);
                   $('label').html(data.d);
               },
               error: OnErrorCall
           });
       }
   ```